# Usar ou não o MainStoryBoard Swift

Tags: swift, swift-3

Comecei os meus estudos em `Swift`, atualmente estou estudando `Swift 4`, mas me deparei com uma duvida, que acredito que muitas pessoas que estejam iniciando tambem tenha (ou não).

No curso que estou vendo, o professor nos ensina a desenvolver `apps` usando o famoso **Arrasta e Solta** do `MainStoryBoard`.

Porem, em outro serie (gringo), eu vi o professor ensinando sem a utilização do `MainStoryBoard`, logo de cara, ele exclui esse arquivo, e tudo que faz (literalmente) é no codigo, desde as constraints até cada elemento do app.

Ai me veio a duvida, qual é a forma certa de desenvolver apps, quais são minhas limitações usando `MainStoryBoard`?

Comment: Não tem imitação nenhuma. É só uma questão de preferência pessoal. Sugiro que aprenda a usar o Interface Builder do Xcode e fazer tudo que se refere a layout nele. Se você está achando difícil auto layout no interface builder imagina se tivesse que fazer programaticamente.

Comment: @LeoDabus não estou achando dificil, até o momento está tranquilo, só não gosto muito dessas `interface Builder`, sempre prefiro fazer tudo na unha, mas querendo ou não, ela adianta muito o trabalho, e por isso, queria saber das limitações.

Comment: Se puder aprender os dois modos melhor ainda

Comment: @LeoDabus então vou fazer isso, aprender os dois.

Comment: Estuda bastante stack views que é o mais importante https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html

Comment: Se tiver alguns links que ache relevante... E Obrigado.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/412/

Answer (score 1):

IMO Esta questão é mais que uma questão de preferencia.

O uso de Storyboard torna realmente certas opções e configurações mais simples e visuais, mas será melhor utilizado em projetos mais pequenos e simples em que exista apenas um developer.

Para sistemas com arquiteturas modelares, projetos maiores e com mais developers, penso que o uso de xib files será mais apropriado pois respeita a modularidade e cada feature e não se perde tempo com merge's de storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

Para mim usar o **.storyboard** me limita bastante, o arrastar e soltar no início até que vai, porque você precisa conhecer como que funciona os componentes na tela, como as constraints funcionam etc. No entanto, conforme você for evoluindo, vai sentir a necessidade de fazer algumas alterações nos componentes e estás alterações só poderão ser feitas por código. O mais legal de fazer via código é que você vai entender como o componente realmente vai se comportar na tela, sem precisar fazer um *force unwrapped* quando você arrastar e soltar um botão do storyboard para VC.